# Overview (List) off Organizations with the same Domain Name within one subscription

Tags: azure-devops, organization

I want to have a list off all the organizations within one subscription.
Some people have made their own organizations and i can see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a complete list of organizations backed by an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant. Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/get-list-of-organizations-connected-to-azure-active-directory?view=azure-devops

> Using any organization backed by your Azure AD, complete the following
>   steps.
>
> 1. Sign in to your organization (`https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}`).
> 2. Select **Organization settings**.
> 3. Select **Azure Active Directory**, and then **Download**.
>      [image]

Comment: Thank You Is very helpfull I have now a overview off the organisations